# Pass a pointer to a proc as an argument

Tags: c++

I want to pass a pointer to a procedure in c++. I tried passing this LRESULT(*)(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM) prc but it didn't work. How is this done?

Thanks

```
HWND OGLFRAME::create(HWND parent, LRESULT(*)(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM) prc)
{
    if(framehWnd != NULL)
    {
        return framehWnd;
        ZeroMemory(&rwc,sizeof(rwc));

    }
```

}

By "it didn't work" I mean it's a syntax error.

```
from the compiler:
Error   2   error C3646: 'prc' : unknown override specifier c:\users\josh\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\vectorizer project\vectorizer project\oglframe.h    10
Error   5   error C3646: 'prc' : unknown override specifier c:\users\josh\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\vectorizer project\vectorizer project\oglframe.cpp  7
Error   1   error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'prc' c:\users\josh\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\vectorizer project\vectorizer project\oglframe.h    10
Error   4   error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'prc' c:\users\josh\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\vectorizer project\vectorizer project\oglframe.cpp  7
Error   3   error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\users\josh\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\vectorizer project\vectorizer project\oglframe.h    10
Error   6   error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\users\josh\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\vectorizer project\vectorizer project\oglframe.cpp  7
```

Comment: And also explain what you mean by "it didn't work". There are many different ways in which it could have "not worked".

Comment: `ZeroMemory(&rwc,sizeof(rwc))` is never going to be called because of `return framehWnd` above it.

Comment: the problem is the parameter LRESULT...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
HWND OGLFRAME::create(HWND parent, LRESULT(*prc)(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM))
```

You could also just use the WNDPROC type:

```
HWND OGLFRAME::create(HWND parent, WNDPROC prc)
```

Comment: Don't forget that the first version needs to use the `CALLBACK` calling convention.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
HWND OGLFRAME::create(HWND parent, LRESULT(*wndproc)(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM))
{

}
```

Comment: Don't forget that window procedures use the `CALLBACK` calling convention.

Answer (score 0):

To declare a function that accepts a function pointer:

```
// Note the CALLBACK calling convention!
HWND OGLFRAME::create(HWND parent,
    LRESULT (CALLBACK *prc)(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM))
{
    // ...
}
```

To pass a function pointer:

```
// Note the CALLBACK calling convention!
LRESULT CALLBACK MyProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
{
    // ...
}

// Note the ampersand!
oglframeinstance.create(hwnd, &MyProc);
```